# display async data in the angular view

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subject-observer

i am fetching the data form an API beck-end and displaying its content in to my view in angular,

for the service i am using observables

```
export class PropertyService {
  apiUrl: string = environment.domain;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private _propertyDetailedInfo = new Subject();
  propertyDetailedInfo$: any = this._propertyDetailedInfo.asObservable();
  updatePropertyDetailedInfo(data: any) {
    this._propertyDetailedInfo.next(data);
    this.propertyDetailedInfo$ = data;
  }


  gerPropertyDetailedInfo(id: string) {
    const res = this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/property?id=${id}`);
    res.subscribe((val) => {
      this.updatePropertyDetailedInfo(val);
      console.log(this.propertyDetailedInfo$);
    });
  }
}
```

and i am subscribing to it in the Component

```
export class PropertySpecsComponent implements OnInit {
  propertyInfo!: any; 
  constructor(private propertyService: PropertyService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    
    this.propertyService.gerPropertyDetailedInfo('90949d476fb');
    this.propertyService.propertyDetailedInfo$.subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.propertyInfo = res;
      console.log(
        ` flexibleCancellation : ${this.propertyInfo.flexibleCancellation}`
      );
    });
  }
}
```

the console.log works and displays what i am looking and even can be displayed in the view with the pipe i am getting the value of `TRUE` for but is cant red the in ng-for

[image]

the code for it:

[image]

error i am getting:

[image]

i trayed to insert the data-object staticly and stored it in service (i did not use observebols) that works displaying the data using json pipe aslo works `{{ propertyInfo.flexibleCancellation | json }}`

but not for `*ngIf="propertyInfo.flexibleCancellation"`

using aysinc pipe dos not work for me

```
*ngIf="propertyInfo.flexibleCancellation | async" i get:
```

[image]

Comment: Async pipe requires an observable, then it subscribes to it and with the response you can do whatever you want inside the template. It looks like you're passing a boolean to the async pipe, that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Add optional chaining "?." to the call of the property like propertyInfo?.flexibleCancellation or wrap your template parts that depends on the value of propertyInfo in an *ngIf="propertyInfo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using optional chaining is a solution no need to use async pipe

```
*ngIf="propertyInfo?.flexibleCancellation"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Analysis**

Probably the view of your component is rendered before the response of the observable is emitted. At that time the proprerty `propertyInfo` is undefined as it does not have an initial value. In your template the call of `flexibleCancellation` on `propertyInfo` leads to a javascript error, becasue `propertyInfo` is not yet defined.

**Possible Solutions:**

1- Use [optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like in ibrahimgb's answer

`*ngIf="propertyInfo?.flexibleCancellation"`

2- Wrap the part of the template that depends on `propertyInfo` in an `*ngIf`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="propertyInfo">
...
</ng-container>
```

And display a loading spinner if the property is undefined

3- Set an empty object as initial Value for `propertyInfo`

```
propertyInfo: any = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

The view is getting rendered before the value of your `propertyInfo` variable is set. Checking whether that value is undefined using `*ngIf` will solve the issue hopefully.